# Erro no programa no VisualG

Tags: visualg, portugol

Estou tendo problemas com esse programa, pois quando coloco pra funcionar e digito um valor maior que 18, aparece uma mensagem dizendo que esta faltando um `FIMSE` e que há um `FIMENQUANTO` sem um `ENQUANTO` correspondente.Esse é o objetivo do programa:Fazer um programa que solicite quinze idades e verifique a faixa etária de acordo com a tabela abaixo. Apresente todos os dados de entrada e saída.

```
inicio 
n <- 0
i <- 0
escreval ("Digite 15 idades: ")
enquanto (i < 15) faca
   leia (n)
   i <- i + 1
   se (n < 18) entao
      escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: criança")
   senao se (n < 30) entao
      escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: jovem")
   senao se (n < 60) entao
      escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: adulto")
   senao
      escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: idoso")
   fimse
fimenquanto
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Tenta eliminar esses "senao's" e bota se(n<18)entao /fimse... se(n>=18 e n<30)entao...fimse .... se(n<60 e n>=30)entao... senao.... fimse

Comment: Vegas eu consegui lhe ajudar? Se minha resposta foi útil, pode deixar um up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema está no modo em que você está utilizando a estrutura de condição:

```
 se (condicao) entao
     <comandos>
 senao
     <comandos>
 fimse
```

Você precisa sempre fechar a estrutura quando inicia ela, então para realizar uma sequencia de verificações você precisa tomar cuidado com a identação do seu portugol. Para que este exemplo da sua pergunta funcione, teria que fazer assim:

```
Algoritmo "teste"
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis
n,i,qtd: inteiro

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...
i <- 0
escreval("Digite quantas idades vc quer classificar: ")
leia(qtd)

 enquanto (i < qtd) faca
   escreval("Digite uma idade: ")
   leia(n)

   se (n < 18) entao
      escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: criança")
   senao
        se (n < 30) entao
           escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: jovem")
        senao
             se(n < 60) entao
                  escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: adulto")
             senao
                  escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: idoso")
             fimse
        fimse
   fimse

   i <- i + 1

 fimenquanto

Fimalgoritmo
```

Veja que fiz uma pequena alteração no inicio dele em que você informa a quantidade de idades que deseja verificar a classificação.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
 inicio 
 n <- 0
 i <- 0
 escreval ("Digite 15 idades: ") 
 para i de 1 ate 15 faca
 leia (n) 
  se (n < 18) entao
  escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: criança")
  fimse
  se (n < 30 e n>18) entao
  escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: jovem")
  fimse
  se (n < 60 e n>30) entao
  escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: adulto")
  fimse
  se(n>60) entao
  escreval ("Sua idade corresponde a classificação: idoso")
  fimse
  fimenquanto
  fimalgoritmo
```

Estava faltando outras comparações nos if's. (repara que tu fez n<18 e n<30 e n<60, se o cara digitasse 17 ele teoricamente iria entrar nas 3 opções. Por isso deu erro. )